# Can i submit a HTML Salesforce form using Ajax with Visual Composer (Raw HTML and Raw JS)

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Actually my question is that I am using Salesforce form in my wordpress website and using Visual Composer , when i use raw HTML and put the Salesforce HTML form on raw HTML element. When I submit the form, it is redirecting on this:  "https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" after submission.
Now I want no redirection. What I want is it should stay on same page or get a success message when a user submits the form. For this purpose I am using this code which is below:

//THE CODE IS MISSING HERE

So I pasted JS code in Raw Js(VC Element) and HTML in Raw Html(VC Element). But it is not working. But it is working when I use it as Simple HTML File.
So I am stuck on this point that why it is not running Visual Composer element.
Now tell me where I am making a mistake.
Thanks and looking forward your soonest response.

Answer (score 0):

The Raw JS is for strict JavaScript.

Are you using basic JavaScript, or a library such as ajax or JQuery? If so, you will need to include a reference to the js library that you are using, for example

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
    '...code here
    });
</script
```